# Styled Components keyframes stop after third refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, styled-components, remix.run

I recently used `styled-components` npm to use in my Remix application.
The animations works fine, but after the third refresh it stops.
I've deployed it on [Netlify](https://qeqrwqrrta.netlify.app/) aswell, but the animation just doens't start there.
This is the code I use

```
import skills from '../js/skills.jsx';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

export default function Test(){
  skills.forEach((skill: any, index) => {
    const moveLeftFirst = keyframes`
    0% {
      left: 110%;
    }
    100% {
      left: -10%;
    }`;
    const IconDiv = styled.div`
      animation: ${moveLeftFirst} 8s infinite linear;
      animation-delay: ${index * 0.8}s;
    `;
    iconDivs.push(IconDiv);
  });

{iconDivs.map((IconDiv, index) => (
  <IconDiv id="skillIcon"
  data-tip
  data-for={skills[index].title}
  className="skillIcon mx-3 justify-center absolute hover:text-white ease-in transition 
  duration-300 left-[110%]"
  onMouseOver={() => stopAnimation(true)}
  onMouseOut={() => stopAnimation(false)}>
    {createElement(skills[index].icon.type, { className: 'w-20 h-20' })}
  </IconDiv>
  ))}
}
```

If you need more info, I'll be happy to give it to you, since I can't exactly explain it in a thread.

Answer (score 1):

You should never define styled components inside another component, always define them at the top level, same when defining animations, see https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-should-i-avoid-declaring-styled-components-in-the-render-method.
So you can move `moveLeftFirst` at the top level, and move `IconDiv` at the top level as well, turning `index` into a transient prop `$index`.